# Why do My Google Search Results Not Visit Page?

Tags: firefox, url, google-search

Hardware: Ubuntu 13.04, firefox-trunk

When I do a google search for "test search," the results returned don't actually link to the URL I thought it would. Instead of pointing to wikipedia, for example, it points to a google URL that THEN redirects to wikipedia. I have noticed that this redirect adds significant time between my click and a website loading. Bing, interestingly, doesn't exhibit this behaviour, nor has the delay, which can last almost instantaneously or as long as ~1.5 seconds!

Is there a way I can circumvent Google hijacking my URL to let me search the web faster? Or should I be using bing?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With those redirection links Google track your clicks in order to personalize your search and perform other necessary analytics.

This is really annoying sometimes. But it can be solved using some extensions:

**For Firefox:**

- [Redirect Remover](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/redirect-remover/) add-on. (Additionally Right click on a redirected URL, it gives an option to copy cleaned URL)

**For Chrome:**

- [Don't track me Google](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/dont-track-me-google/gdbofhhdmcladcmmfjolgndfkpobecpg) at Chrome Web Store.
- [Remove Google Redirects](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/remove-google-redirects/ccenmflbeofaceccfhhggbagkblihpoh) at Chrome Web Store.
- [Don't track me Google](http://userscripts.org/scripts/show/121923) at userscripts.org

For more information on the issue refer [here](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/22291/turning-off-google-search-results-indirection) at *webapps.stackexchange.com*.